# Can't call destructor from inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

I have an abstract class, which i'm inheriting from.
To make it clear- I implemented all of the abstract methods in the inheritor.

After done using the object made from the inheritor class, im trying to destruct it, but instead of calling the inherited destructor it sends me to the abstract method.

in my programm it look like this

```
class LinkedHash {

private:
      LinkedHashEntry **table;
      int max_size;
public:
      /* Creates a hashtable of size maxSize*/
      LinkedHash(int);
      LinkedHash(){}       
      /* deletes all members of the hashtable */
      virtual ~LinkedHash();

      virtual int hashFunction(int key) = 0;

      void insert(int key, Process* value);

      void remove(int  key);
      int getMaxSize(){return max_size;}
      LinkedHashEntry* search(int x);
};

class LinkedHashinheritor: public LinkedHash {

    public:
        LinkedHashinheritor():LinkedHash(1000){}
        int hashFunction(int key);
};
```

this is my cpp file relevant code:

```
int LinkedHashinheritor::hashFunction(int key)
{
    return key%1000;
}
```

and there are the calling for constructor and destructor for the relevant object:

```
   Scheduler::Scheduler()
{tmp_lh=new LinkedHashinheritor();}

Scheduler::~Scheduler()
{
    delete tmp_lh;
}
```

Comment: have you provided an implementation for your base destructor? Have you provided a destructor for your derived class?

Comment: Have you tried doing a full rebuild of your project?  Sometimes bad stuff can happen if a header file changes (e.g. by adding a new virtual method to a class) and source files that include that header don't get recompiled.

Comment: yes, sure- my base destructor is implemented. i didn't even declared the desructor for my derived class, it should be calle autumatically by the compiler, isn't it?

Comment: Are you not expecting the base class destructor to be called? If so, that is an incorrect expectation.

Comment: declaring the derived class destructor not solving the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this clear upfront: Making a class abstract does **not** prevent its destroctor from being called. The destructors of *all* classes in an inheritance hierarchy will *always* be called (in the order from derived class to base class).

As you have not declared a destructor in your derived class, and the compiler-provided one is extremely trivial (as in, it only has to call the destructor from the base class), it is very well possible that the compiler has optimised the derived destructor away.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `virtual` destructors are special `virtual` functions: The base class destructors are always called when destroying a derived object. The effect of making a destructor `virtual` is that you can `delete` an object of a derived type through a pointer to the base type (if you do this without the destructor being `virtual` you get undefined behavior.